# how do i use tkinter to open a new script, then when closing the new window return to the first script?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

these two scripts worked fine seperatly and after many differant approches i have got the *page1* to open *menu_func* however when i close *menu_func* the window remains but deletes the photos etc?
i want the *back* command to return to the *page1* script

i also get this error,

> invalid command name "36335088time_now"
> while executing
> "36335088time_now"
> ("after" script)

not related to my actual problem but if anybody knows how to get rid of it help would be appreciated

1.*page1* code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import strftime
import subprocess
import menu_func

    
page1 = tk.Toplevel()
width_value=page1.winfo_screenwidth()
height_value=page1.winfo_screenheight()
page1.geometry('%dx%d-0+0' % (width_value, height_value))
page1.resizable(False, False)

BG1_img = Image.open('BG-BLK-1.png')
BG2_img = BG1_img.resize((width_value,height_value))
BG3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BG2_img)

canvas = Canvas(page1)
canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
limg = Label(canvas, i=BG3_img)
limg.pack()

SD1_img = Image.open('Bshut.png')
SD2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(SD1_img)

MU1_img = Image.open('./LIST.png')
MU2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(MU1_img)


def close():
page1.destroy()

#def MU_COMM():
#    import menu_func.py
#    page1.exit()
#    exec(open('menu_func.py').read())

def time_now():
    T_D = strftime('%A, %d %h %Y %H:%M:%S')
    show_date.config(text = T_D)
    show_date.after(1000, time_now)

exit_button = Button(canvas,image=SD2_img, 
command=close,borderwidth='0',border='0',bg='#000000', highlightthickness='0')    
exit_button.place(x=1700, y=900)

show_date = Label(canvas, font="Calibri, 46", fg="red", border='0',bg='#00090e')
show_date.place(x=440, y=960)

menu_button = Button(canvas, image=MU2_img, command= menu_func.menu, borderwidth=0, 
bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
menu_button.place(x=50, y=900)


time_now()
page1.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 'True')
page1.mainloop()
```

2.*menu_func* code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import strftime

def menu():
    pageM = tk.Toplevel()
    w_v=pageM.winfo_screenwidth()
    h_v=pageM.winfo_screenheight()
    pageM.geometry('%dx%d-0+0' % (w_v, h_v))
    pageM.resizable(False, False)
    BG1m_img = Image.open('BG-BLK-1.png')
    BG2m_img = BG1m_img.resize((w_v,h_v))
    BG3m_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(BG2m_img)
    canvas = Canvas(pageM)
    butt_W = int(w_v/28)
    butt_H = int(h_v/31)
    img_W = int(w_v/8)
    img_H = int(h_v/4)
    canvas = Canvas(pageM)
    canvas.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    limg = Label(canvas, i=BG3m_img)
    limg.pack()

    def time_now():
        T_D = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        show_time.config(text = T_D)
        show_time.after(1000, time_now)

    show_time = Label(canvas, font="Calibri, 46", fg="red", border='0',bg='#003a52')
    show_time.place(x=int(w_v/2.3), y=int(h_v/50))

    def call_COM():
        showinfo(title='Information',message='phone Button clicked!')
    call_img = Image.open('CALL.png')
    cal1_img = call_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    cal2_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cal1_img)
    button1=tk.Button(canvas, image=(cal2_img),borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button1.place(x=int(w_v/5*1-(img_W)+50),y=int(h_v/3*0.8-(img_H/2)))

    def map_COM():
        exec(open("mapscreen.py").read())  
    c1_img = Image.open('comp.png')
    c2_img = c1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    c3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(c2_img)
    button2=tk.Button(canvas, image=c3_img,command=map_COM,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button2.place(x=int(w_v/5*2-(img_W/1.2)+50),y=int(h_v/3*0.8-(img_H/2)))

    def user_COM():
        showinfo(title='Information',message='user Button clicked!')
    u1_img = Image.open('user.png')
    u2_img = u1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    u3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(u2_img)
    button3=tk.Button(canvas, image=u3_img,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button3.place(x=int(w_v/5*3-(img_W/1.5)+50),y=int(h_v/3*0.8-(img_H/2)))

    def set_COM():
        showinfo(title='Information',message='settings Button clicked!')
    s1_img = Image.open('settings.png')
    s2_img = s1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    s3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(s2_img)
    button4=tk.Button(canvas, image=s3_img,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button4.place(x=int(w_v/5*4-(img_W/2)+50),y=int(h_v/3*0.8-(img_H/2)))

    def bro_COM():
        exec(open('browser.py').read())
    b1_img = Image.open('brows.png')
    b2_img = b1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    b3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(b2_img)
    button5=tk.Button(canvas, image=b3_img,command=bro_COM,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button5.place(x=int(w_v/5*1-(img_W)+50),y=int(h_v/3*2.2-(img_H/1.5)))

    def mus_COM():
        showinfo(title='Information',message='Music Button clicked!')
    m1_img = Image.open('music.png')
    m2_img = m1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    m3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(m2_img)
    button6=tk.Button(canvas, image=m3_img,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button6.place(x=int(w_v/5*2-(img_W/1.2)+50),y=int(h_v/3*2.2-(img_H/1.5)))

    def lite_COMM():
        showinfo(title='Information',message='hardware Button clicked!')
    t1_img = Image.open('Torch.png')
    t2_img = t1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    t3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(t2_img)
    button7=tk.Button(canvas, image=t3_img,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button7.place(x=int(w_v/5*3-(img_W/1.5)+50),y=int(h_v/3*2.2-(img_H/1.5)))

    def back_COM():
        pageM.quit()
#        exec(open('start_screen.py').read())
    SD1_img = Image.open('home.png')
    SD2_img = SD1_img.resize((img_W,img_H))
    SD3_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(SD2_img)
    button8=tk.Button(canvas, image=SD3_img,command=back_COM,borderwidth=0,bg='#000000', highlightthickness=0)
    button8.place(x=int(w_v/5*4-(img_W/2)+50),y=int(h_v/3*2.2-(img_H/1.5)))


    time_now()
    print(w_v/5*4-(img_W/2))
    print(w_v/5*1-(img_W))
    print(img_W)
    print(h_v)
    print(w_v)
    pageM.mainloop()
```

the *print(variables)* arnt really part of the script there just there to help me work out locations of widgets!

i also understand this is a long code, if anybody know a way to make it shorter or more efficient please let me know, im not a programmer
thanks

Comment: it is also creating a small window with nothing in? i cant seam to find where its coming from?

Comment: so apparently adding a **print("back clicked")** after **def back_COM():** has made it return back to the first screen without errors